# Unable to compile C++ code after Xcode upgrade: <sys/cdefs.h> no such file or directory

Tags: terminal, xcode, macports

After upgrading macOS BigSur to 11.1 and Xcode to 12.3 this morning my MacPorts 2.6.4 distribution started to have problems. I can no longer compile a simple C++ program with the GNU C++ v10.2.0_4:

```
g++ -O3 -std=c++11 -c libvec.cpp
In file included from /opt/local/include/gcc10/c++/cmath:45,
             from libvec.cpp:1:
/opt/local/lib/gcc10/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin20/10.2.0/include-fixed/math.h:45:10: fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory
45 | #include <sys/cdefs.h>
   |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Preliminary internet search suggests that this problem may be caused by the inconsistency with the Xcode command line tools. Would you please direct me, on how to debug and fix it? Maybe I need to reinstall the MacPorts distribution after such an upgrade? Thank you!

Comment: Look at the macports mailing lists and ask tgere

Answer (score 3):

This issue is indeed caused by the macOS update from 11.0 to 11.1 and Xcode update from 12.2 to 12.3. Apple's new policy is to increment the SDK version with each system update. The MacPorts GNU C++ compiler installed with a previous SDK version fails now due to this increment. A quick workaround is to set the `SDKROOT` environment variable to match the new version number:

```
export SDKROOT=`xcrun --show-sdk-path`
```

Place this command into your `~/.profile` file for convenience. Detailed issue explanation and this solution may be found in the [following thread](http://mac-os-forge.2317878.n4.nabble.com/latest-update-to-BigSur-11-1-broke-gcc-td408729.html) on MacPorts mailing list.